# Identify frequency of elements in each key in python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary as follows.

```
mylist = [ {"0": ["code1", "code5"], "1" ["code8", "code7", "code2"]}, 
{"1": ["code2", "code3"], "2" ["code4", "code5", "code7"], "3": ["code1", "code10"]}, 
{"0": ["code8", "code5", "code1"], "2" ["code7", "code5", "code2"]} ]
```

Now, I want to calculate the codes count for each key in the dictionary. For example `"0": ["code1", "code5"]` and `"0": ["code8", "code5"]` should give: `mydict_for_0 = {"code1": 1, "code5": 2, "code8": 1}`

So, for the above `mylist` the output should be;

```
mydict_for_0 = {"code1": 2, "code5": 2, "code8": 1}
mydict_for_1 = {"code2": 2, "code3": 1, "code7": 1, "code8": 1}
mydict_for_2 = {"code4": 1, "code5": 2, "code7": 2, {"code2": 1}
mydict_for_3 = {"code1": 1, "code10": 1}
```

Please help me to do this using python!

Comment: This is not a coding services website. Do you own work and when you run into a more specific issue, post it here.

Comment: What you are tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `defaultdict`, `Counter` from `collections` module, find all same key's value list, extend them into one list, save into a `defaultdict(list)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for e in mylist:
    for key,value in e.items():
        new_dict[key].extend(value)
```

`new_dict` will be:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'0': ['code1', 'code5', 'code8', 'code5', 'code1'],
             '1': ['code8', 'code7', 'code2', 'code2', 'code3'],
             '2': ['code4', 'code5', 'code7', 'code7', 'code5', 'code2'],
             '3': ['code1', 'code10']})
```

After that, loop all items to pass the values list into `Counter`, to count the occurrences of list:

```
result = {}
for key,value in new_dict.items():
    result['mydict_for_'+key] = dict(Counter(value))
```

`result` will be:

```
{'mydict_for_0': {'code1': 2, 'code5': 2, 'code8': 1},
 'mydict_for_1': {'code2': 2, 'code3': 1, 'code7': 1, 'code8': 1},
 'mydict_for_2': {'code2': 1, 'code4': 1, 'code5': 2, 'code7': 2},
 'mydict_for_3': {'code1': 1, 'code10': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the solution

```
final_result = []
for i in mylist:
    current_list = mylist[i]
    d = {}
    for key in current_list:
        try:
            d[m]+=1
        except KeyError as e:
            d.update({m: 1})
        final_result.append(d)

for i in final_result:
    print(i)
```